# Spark Scala 2.10 tuple limit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, tuples, dataframe, limit

I have DataFrame with 66 columns to process (almost each column value needs to be changed someway) so I'm running following statement

```
    val result = data.map(row=> (
        modify(row.getString(row.fieldIndex("XX"))),
        (...)
        )
    )
```

till 66th column.
Since scala in this version has limit to max tuple of 22 pairs I cannot perform this like that.
Question is, is there any workaround for it?
After all line operations I'm converting it to df with specific column names

```
   result.toDf("c1",...,"c66")
   result.storeAsTempTable("someFancyResult")
```

"modify" function is just an example to show my point

Comment: switch to scala 2.11 ?

Comment: I wish that could be so simple, but it's not the case

Comment: @Odomontois AFAIK Scala 2.11 does not support tuples of cardinality >22, i.e. there is no Tuple23.

Comment: @Odomontois I have scala 2.11.2, and I still have limit in 22 items for tuple. I guess this was not introduced in scala release yet

Comment: Probably first step is easy to workaround, just to create tuple of tuples (or case classes. What about next - you should regain your dataframe via manual mapping

Comment: @Archeg. Hm interesting. The limit for case classes was definitely removed starting from 2.11.0

Comment: AFAIK case class in scala has same problem with tuple >22, How should this regain look like? Cause I'm afraid when I join my touples together I'll run the same problem during creation of DF

Comment: @Archeg Yes. It's solved for case classes but still open and even not planned to resolve for tuples https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7099?jql=labels%20%3D%20twenty-two

Comment: @Odomontois Interesting discussion: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7621622 It seems like only case class limit was removed. I don't think you can remove Tuple limit without code generation, and they don't have it for tuple yet, so it's hard to introduce. It's easy for case clases - as they are generated anyway. Still the `unapply` is not generated for a case class of arity > 22

Comment: @Silverrose I think one way to fix your problem is to try using `shapeless` with `spark`, but I have no idea how complex this might be. This seems to be someones try: https://github.com/tresata/spark-columnar

Comment: spliting this into tuple of tuples is fine but how should I create DF from it then? I'll take a look at ColumnarRDD but I guess that won't solve the problem with DF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you do is modifying values from an existing `DataFrame` it is better to use an UDF instead of mapping over a RDD:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val modifyUdf = udf(modify)
data.withColumn("c1", modifyUdf($"c1"))
```

If for some reason above doesn't fit your needs the simplest thing you can do is to recreate`DataFrame` from a `RDD[Row]`. for example like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField, StructType, IntegerType}


val result: RDD[Row] = data.map(row => {
  val buffer = ArrayBuffer.empty[Any]

  // Add value to buffer
  buffer.append(modify(row.getAs[String]("c1")))

  // ... repeat for other values

  // Build row
  Row.fromSeq(buffer)
})

// Create schema
val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("c1", StringType, false),
  // ...  
  StructField("c66", StringType, false)
))

sqlContext.createDataFrame(result, schema)
```

Comment: True, if he's already got a Dataframe, this is the simpler route

Comment: @Ewan It looks like this is the case. It is not only the simplest approach but also much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is what saves me :)

Comment: @Silverrose I am glad to hear that :) Please don't forget to upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

The way around it is pretty fiddly, but it does work, try this sample code to get you started, you can see there are more than 22 columns being accessed:

```
object SimpleApp {
  class Record(val x1: String, val x2: String, val x3: String, ... val x24:String) extends Product with Serializable {
    def canEqual(that: Any) = that.isInstanceOf[Record]

    def productArity = 24

    def productElement(n: Int) = n match {
      case 0 => x1
      case 1 => x2
      case 2 => x3
      ...
      case 23 => x24
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Product Test")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);

    val record = new Record("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x")

    import sqlContext._
    sc.parallelize(record :: Nil).registerAsTable("records")

    sql("SELECT x1 FROM records").collect()
  }
}
```