# Error With Multiple withColumn in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This line of code is not working the way I thought it would:

```
val df2 = df1
  .withColumn("email_age", when('age_of_email <= 60, 1))
  .withColumn("email_age", when('age_of_email <= 120, 2))
  .withColumn("email_age", when('age_of_email <= 180, 3).otherwise(4))
```

I have thousands of lines in df1 with `age_of_email` that are less than 60 and/or less than 120, but all my lines are getting categorized as **3** or **4**:

Any insight into why this is happening?

Comment: How are we supposed to answer your question without knowing what library you're using or anything...

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? : `import org.apache.spark.sql._` , `import org.apache.spark.ml._`

Comment: Why would you assume that we knew that you were using spark?

Comment: I've never used spark, but it looks like you can't use `.withColumn` on the same column more than once. Your last call is overwriting your previous ones. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908448/spark-add-column-to-dataframe-conditionally

Comment: You are using the same column name in all the three withColumn methods. You should use a different name on each of that method. And age <= 60 or <= 120 is <= 180 too :-) This is why you see all the groups as 3 (because the column name is same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people have said in the comments, using `withColumn` with a column name that is already in the dataframe will replace that column.

I think for what you want to achieve you might either use different column names for each categorization or simply concatenate the `when()` in a single column like

```
val df2 = df1.withColumn("email_age", when('age_of_email <= 60, 1)
                                     .when('age_of_email <= 120, 2)
                                     .when('age_of_email <= 180, 3)
                                     .otherwise(4))
```

I guess you're aware that the categories are subsets of category `3`