# How to add header and column to dataframe spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I have got a dataframe, on which I want to add a header and a first column
manually. Here is the dataframe :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession 

val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("my-spark-app").getOrCreate()
val df = spark.read.option("header",true).option("inferSchema",true).csv("C:\\gg.csv").cache()
```

the content of the dataframe

```
12,13,14
11,10,5
3,2,45
```

The expected output is

```
define,col1,col2,col3
c1,12,13,14
c2,11,10,5
c3,3,2,45
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is:

```
df.withColumn("columnName", column) //here "columnName" should be "define" for you
```

Now you just need to create the said column ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908448/spark-add-column-to-dataframe-conditionally) might help)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'column' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that depends on Spark 2.4:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

//First off the dataframe needs to be loaded with the expected schema

val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName().getOrCreate()

val schema = new StructType()
              .add("col1",IntegerType,true)
              .add("col2",IntegerType,true)
              .add("col3",IntegerType,true)

val df = spark.read.format("csv").schema(schema).load("C:\\gg.csv").cache()

val rddWithId = df.rdd.zipWithIndex

// Prepend "define" column of type Long
val newSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("define", StringType, false))         ++ df.schema.fields)

val dfZippedWithId =  spark.createDataFrame(rddWithId.map{ 
                       case (row, index) => 
                       Row.fromSeq(Array("c" + index) ++ row.toSeq)}, newSchema)
// Show results
dfZippedWithId.show
```

Displays:

```
+------+----+----+----+
|define|col1|col2|col3|
+------+----+----+----+
|    c0|  12|  13|  14|
|    c1|  11|  10|   5|
|    c2|   3|   2|  45|
+------+----+----+----+
```

This is a mix of the documentation [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/read-csv.html) and this [example](https://gist.github.com/zouzias/44723de11222535223fe59b4b0bc228c).