# Compare two dataset and get what fields are changed

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I am working on a spark using *Java*, where I will download data from api and compare with mongodb data, while the downloaded json have 15-20 fields but database have 300 fields.

Now my task is to compare the downloaded jsons to mongodb data, and get whatever fields changed with past data.

#### Sample data set

*Downloaded data from API*

```
StudentId,Name,Phone,Email
1,tony,123,a@g.com
2,stark,456,b@g.com
3,spidy,789,c@g.com
```

*Mongodb data*

```
StudentId,Name,Phone,Email,State,City
1,tony,1234,a@g.com,NY,Nowhere
2,stark,456,bg@g.com,NY,Nowhere
3,spidy,789,c@g.com,OH,Nowhere
```

I can't use the except, because of column length.

*Expected output*

```
StudentId,Name,Phone,Email,Past_Phone,Past_Email
1,tony,1234,a@g.com,1234, //phone number only changed 
2,stark,456,b@g.com,,bg@g.com //Email only changed
3,spidy,789,c@g.com,,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your data is in 2 dataframes. We can create temporary views for them, as shown below,

```
api_df.createOrReplaceTempView("api_data")
mongo_df.createOrReplaceTempView("mongo_data")
```

Next we can use Spark SQL. Here, we join both these views using the `StudentId` column and then use a case statement on top of them to compute the past phone number and email.

```
spark.sql("""
select a.*
, case when a.Phone = b.Phone then '' else b.Phone end as Past_phone
, case when a.Email = b.Email then '' else b.Email end as Past_Email
from api_data a
join mongo_data b
on a.StudentId = b.StudentId
order by a.StudentId""").show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+-----+-----+-------+----------+----------+
|StudentId| Name|Phone|  Email|Past_phone|Past_Email|
+---------+-----+-----+-------+----------+----------+
|        1| tony|  123|a@g.com|      1234|          |
|        2|stark|  456|b@g.com|          |  bg@g.com|
|        3|spidy|  789|c@g.com|          |          |
+---------+-----+-----+-------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below same source code. Here I am taking the only phone number condition as an example.

```
val list = List((1,"tony",123,"a@g.com"), (2,"stark",456,"b@g.com") 
       (3,"spidy",789,"c@g.com"))
val df1 = list.toDF("StudentId","Name","Phone","Email")
     .select('StudentId as "StudentId_1", 'Name as "Name_1",'Phone as "Phone_1", 
     'Email as "Email_1")

df1.show()

val list1 = List((1,"tony",1234,"a@g.com","NY","Nowhere"), 
     (2,"stark",456,"bg@g.com", "NY", "Nowhere"),
     (3,"spidy",789,"c@g.com","OH","Nowhere"))

val df2 = list1.toDF("StudentId","Name","Phone","Email","State","City")
      .select('StudentId as "StudentId_2", 'Name as "Name_2", 'Phone as "Phone_2",
         'Email as "Email_2", 'State as "State_2", 'City as "City_2")

df2.show()

val df3 = df1.join(df2, df1("StudentId_1") === 
         df2("StudentId_2")).where(df1("Phone_1") =!= df2("Phone_2"))

df3.withColumnRenamed("Phone_1", "Past_Phone").show()

+-----------+------+-------+-------+
|StudentId_1|Name_1|Phone_1|Email_1|
+-----------+------+-------+-------+
|          1|  tony|    123|a@g.com|
|          2| stark|    456|b@g.com|
|          3| spidy|    789|c@g.com|
+-----------+------+-------+-------+

+-----------+------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
|StudentId_2|Name_2|Phone_2| Email_2|State_2| City_2|
+-----------+------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
|          1|  tony|   1234| a@g.com|     NY|Nowhere|
|          2| stark|    456|bg@g.com|     NY|Nowhere|
|          3| spidy|    789| c@g.com|     OH|Nowhere|
+-----------+------+-------+--------+-------+-------+

+-----------+------+----------+-------+-----------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|StudentId_1|Name_1|Past_Phone|Email_1|StudentId_2|Name_2|Phone_2|Email_2|State_2| City_2|
+-----------+------+----------+-------+-----------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|          1|  tony|       123|a@g.com|          1|  tony|   1234|a@g.com|     NY|Nowhere|
+-----------+------+----------+-------+-----------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you fro the quick answer but,my expected table should not have state,city.Should be showing only fields which changed if not empty.I advance I don't know which fields from df1 are changing , so it should be dynamic

Comment: Okay. Do we have any specific column which will always exist?

Answer (score 0):

We have :

```
df1.show
+-----------+------+-------+-------+
|StudentId_1|Name_1|Phone_1|Email_1|
+-----------+------+-------+-------+
|          1|  tony|    123|a@g.com|
|          2| stark|    456|b@g.com|
|          3| spidy|    789|c@g.com|
+-----------+------+-------+-------+

df2.show

+-----------+------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
|StudentId_2|Name_2|Phone_2| Email_2|State_2| City_2|
+-----------+------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
|          1|  tony|   1234| a@g.com|     NY|Nowhere|
|          2| stark|    456|bg@g.com|     NY|Nowhere|
|          3| spidy|    789| c@g.com|     OH|Nowhere|
+-----------+------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
```

After Join :

```
var jn = df2.join(df1,df1("StudentId_1")===df2("StudentId_2"))
```

Then

```
var ans = jn.withColumn("Past_Phone", when(jn("Phone_2").notEqual(jn("Phone_1")),jn("Phone_1")).otherwise("")).withColumn("Past_Email", when(jn("Email_2").notEqual(jn("Email_1")),jn("Email_1")).otherwise(""))
```

Reference : [Spark: Add column to dataframe conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908448/spark-add-column-to-dataframe-conditionally)

Next :

```
ans.select(ans("StudentId_2") as "StudentId",ans("Name_2") as "Name",ans("Phone_2") as "Phone",ans("Email_2") as "Email",ans("Past_Email"),ans("Past_Phone")).show

+---------+-----+-----+--------+----------+----------+
|StudentId| Name|Phone|   Email|Past_Email|Past_Phone|
+---------+-----+-----+--------+----------+----------+
|        1| tony| 1234| a@g.com|          |       123|
|        2|stark|  456|bg@g.com|   b@g.com|          |
|        3|spidy|  789| c@g.com|          |          |
+---------+-----+-----+--------+----------+----------+
```