# How to add large struct column to dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, case-class

I want to add a struct column to a dataframe, but the struct has more than **100** fields.
I learned that **case class** can be changed to struct column, but case class has the limit of no more than 22 fields(online spark is 1.6.3 with scala of 2.10.4).
Can **normal class** do this? What functions or interface I have to implement?
There is also a "**org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct**", but seems that it can't set the name of the fields of the struct.
Thanks ahead.

Comment: go for UDF if its possible .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826495/spark-scala-2-10-tuple-limit

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by not able to set field name of struct. you can do this like this
val fields =new StructField("name", StringType, false) :: new StructField("age", IntegerType, false) :: List(new StructField("age", IntegerType, false))

Comment: Thanks Balaji Reddy. Now I already have a dataframe which has about 40 columns, and want to add a new column which type is struct. Do you mean I have to define a new struct which conclude the existing 40 fields and the new struct which has more than 100 fields?

Comment: newer version of spark doesn't have 22 fields limit for case class. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but seems that it can't set the name of the fields of the struct.

You can. For example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

spark.range(1).withColumn("foo", 
   struct($"id".alias("x"), lit("foo").alias("y"), struct($"id".alias("bar")))
).printSchema

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- foo: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- x: long (nullable = false)
 |    |-- y: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- col3: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- bar: long (nullable = false)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to define case class for this struct, you can create struct type this way:

```
val struct =
  StructType(
    StructField("a", IntegerType, true) ::
    StructField("b", LongType, false) ::
    StructField("c", BooleanType, false) :: Nil)
```

This struct can have arbitrary length.

then you can read dataframe this way

```
val df = sparkSession.read.schema(struct).//your read method
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I already have a dataframe which has about 40 columns, and want to add a new column which type is struct. Do you mean I have to define a new struct which conclude the existing 40 fields and the new struct?